# Can I use a json array field in combination with an IN clause

Tags: mysql, json

I have this query which is working:

```
select * 
from housedata 
where JSON_EXTRACT(properties->"$.Type", '$[0]') in ('House', 'Flat');
```

However in certain rows there is more then one item in the Type json Array, and I don't want to just use the first item like in the example above.

Suppose it's ["House", "Flat"] I'd like to match the query, but also when it's ["House", "Tent"] as one of the items in the "In" list matches.

Is this possible in a query? I've tried to find it but I keep on finding examples of finding something in the JSON array itself but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: `JSON_EXTRACT(properties->"$.Type", '$[0]')` will return not `'House'` but `'"House"'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this works (tested in MySQL 8.0.32):

```
select json_extract(properties->'$.Type', '$[0]') IN ('House', 'Flat') as result 
from housedata;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
```

If you want to test for any value in your JSON array matching one of a list of values, then use JSON_OVERLAPS():

```
select true from housedata
where json_overlaps(properties->'$.Type',
  cast('["House","Flat"]' as json));
+------+
| true |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

Of course this would be much simpler if you did not use JSON for your multi-valued properties, but instead used a dependent table, and stored one value per row.

```
select ...
from housedata join housedata_type using (house_id)
where housedata_type.type in ('House', 'Flat');
```

Comment: thanks! Somehow I didn't find this JSON_OVERLAPS. As for your simpler approach, you are right but this storing simplified the data import and displaying a lot, I might change it later as it's probably a lot faster to handle for the DB

Comment: I don't think it will be faster. It can't use an index as far as I can tell, so queries using JSON_OVERLAPS() will be forced to do table-scans.